# SQL Rowsource not working anymore after loading in values from another table

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I have created a form whose comboboxes get "DISTINCT"-populated with values (from a table), which means nothing is selected at first, but the combobox offers a load of values to select from named table. In Field 1 I select a value and then Field 2 automatically loads in only values from the table where the criteria fits the value from the first field and so on. This way, I am narrowing down the numbers of applying recordsets from my table down to 1 or 2 just by clicking and choosing options. [My Form looks this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt5fq.png).

I have a total of 16 rows where in each row I can narrow down parameters to 1 specific item from the table.

With pressing a button, I can write these values into another table where they will get a save ID and a save name. This all works flawlessly.

I also added a loading button, where I can select the savenames from the savetable and the form will automatically get filled with the values from the savetable. But as soon as I do this, no values are suggested anymore in the field that contains multiple Columns. I tried a Requery, I tried reassigning the Rowsource, I tried just deleting the values in the fields before, nothing helps. I have to use my "erase" function where I set all fields to "Null" to be able to get the "suggesting values" back to work.[This is how it looks after loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koC0I.png)
In the regarding field should be at least 3 values which get not displayed anymore.

It feels like filling the forms' fields with comboboxname.value = rs!valuefromsavetable deletes or blocks the rowsources from working.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We cannot guess how the form works without code and your description is not enough to help explain or debug the details.  Please share relevant Form code and/or Rowsource queries, etc.  Also, the images are not very useful since there are no column headers and only abstract numbers displayed in some of the Comboboxes... no good way to interpret what we're seeing, especially since the Rowsource property effects the drop-down list, but that is not shown.

Comment: Unfortunatley, the data and names I am using are classified. I will try to work out a simple example, but this will take time as my project has over 15000 lines of code and is pretty complex.

Comment: Nevermind, I removed 2 write/read commands and now miraculously, it works. But not on the old Saves, that have had an entry from these values. These were normal values but seemed to have corrupted the table. One of these values has been read and written into a hidden field on the form.

Comment: I'm glad that you got part of it working.  "Compact and Repair" if you feel that data is actually corrupt.  Definitely don't post confidential info... but rarely will basic descriptions be enough to answer such a question, so you'll need some way of using aliases in code snippets and showing useful sample data.  Sometimes blurring data in images is useful, but showing a blank dropdown list is not useful since stating as much in text is sufficient.  If the code itself is confidential, you'll have a hard time getting adequate help on a public site.  Best of luck.

Comment: I guess that you requery each combobox when a value in the previous combobox is selected. Unfortunately, this will not only affect the combobox in the same row but all such comboboxes in that same column, so this will not work in a continuous form like your's.

Comment: it works as intended now. The problem seems to have been a value written and read from a hidden field within the form. Once I removed writing/reading from that field, everything was perfect